# MongoDB how to update array of objects with id and updated values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have array of objects:

```
[
 {_id: "5ca2141da0106d1320c0ae32", detail: 1},
 {_id: "5ca2141da0106d1320c0ae33", detail: 3},
 {_id: "5ca2141da0106d1320c0ae34", detail: 3}
]
```

How i can update document by id and its value from array?
I'm trying to do it this way:

```
arrayOfObjects.map(i => {
        ids.push(i._id);
        details.push(i.detail);
    });
Model.updateMany(
        { _id: { $in: ids } },
        { $set: { detail: details} },
```

should i get an index of `$in: ids` for my `set` operator?

Comment: Hi bulldojka, I didn't understand what is the expected outcome. Could you post what is the result you're expecting?

Comment: Hi. I wanted to update my documents by id in array. I thought it could be done with a "updateMany". But that's not how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your array.

```
var arrayofObjects = [
  {_id: "5ca2141da0106d1320c0ae32", detail: 1},
  {_id: "5ca2141da0106d1320c0ae33", detail: 3},
  {_id: "5ca2141da0106d1320c0ae34", detail: 3}
]

arrayOfObjects.forEach(function(obj) {
  Model.update({"_id": obj._id}, {"$set": {"detail": obj.detail}}, callback);
});
```

**UpdateMany** is **db.Collection** collection object. [Refer link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/).

Answer (score 1):

Prior to Mongo version 4.2 you have to execute each update separately as they have different conditions, this is best done using [bulkWrite](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) in order to save up on network overhead, like so:

```
const input = [
    {_id: ObjectId("5ca2141da0106d1320c0ae32"), detail: 1},
    {_id: ObjectId("5ca2141da0106d1320c0ae33"), detail: 3},
    {_id: ObjectId("5ca2141da0106d1320c0ae34"), detail: 3}
];

const bulk = [];
input.forEach((datum) => {
    bulk.push(
        {
            updateOne: {
                "filter": {_id: datum._id},
                "update": {$set: {detail: datum.detail}}
            }
        }
    )
})

await db.collection.bulkWrite(bulk)
```

Version 4.2 introduced [pipelined updates](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) which allows us to use aggregation operators in the update body, now we can execute a single update and leverage this power, you can achieve the update in multiple ways here is one example:

```
const input = [
    {_id: ObjectId("5ca2141da0106d1320c0ae32"), detail: 1},
    {_id: ObjectId("5ca2141da0106d1320c0ae33"), detail: 3},
    {_id: ObjectId("5ca2141da0106d1320c0ae34"), detail: 3}
];

db.collection.updateMany(
    { _id: {$in: input.map(v => v._id )}},
    [
        {
            $set: {
                detail: {
                    $getField: {
                        field: "detail",
                        input: {
                            $first: {
                                $filter: {
                                    input: input,
                                    cond: {
                                        $eq: [
                                            "$$this._id",
                                            "$_id"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zS8D_TwzAXQ)