# mongoose - update many from an array of Ids

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

im trying to update all keys ('indexOrder') in an array of objects in a document.
The values for the update are recived as an array from the client:

```
[{_id:'1s284hd72hdd', indexOrder: 1}, {_id:'543543531', indexOrder: 2}, etc..]
```

im trying to match the _id of the array from the client with the _id of the objects in the document. When a match is found -> it needs to update the 'indexOrder' in the document to its value from the array from the client.

currently im doing it with looping on the client array, and updating for each iteration.

```
  async updateIndexOrder(orderList) {
    try {
      orderList.forEach(async ({_id, indexOrder}) => {
        await Model.findOneAndUpdate({_id}, {$set:{indexOrder}})
      })
      return true;

  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }
}
```

How can I update in one call instead of so many server calls?
something like:

```
  async updateIndexOrder(orderList) {
    const idList= orderList.map(x => x._id)
    try {
      await Model.updatMany(
    {_id: {$in:{idList}},
    {$set: {indexOrder: orderList[FIND INDEX OF THE ITERATING _id].indexOrder}}
    )

  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Answered very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74561802/10770370).

Comment: How do you "FIND INDEX OF THE ITERATING _id" though??

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in mongodb 4.2 and onwards

```
    exports.updateDIndexOrder = async (keyValPairArr) => {
    try {
        let data = await Model.collection.update(
            { _id: { $in: keyValPairArr.map(o => o._id) } },
            [{
                $set: {
                    indexOrder: {
                        $let: {
                            vars: { obj: { $arrayElemAt: [{ $filter: { input: keyValPairArr, as: "kvpa", cond: { $eq: ["$$kvpa.id", "$_id"] } } }, 0] } },
                            in: "$$obj.indexOrder"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }],
            { runValidators: true, multi: true }
        )

        return data;
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
}
```